# inserting double quotes on bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying this bash script  but not able to insert double quotes. This is my actual script.

```
 mysql -u root -pH0tjava1 -B -e \
   "select concat('sshpass\`' , '-p\`', '"Password\"', 'rsync\`',
                  '-avvtzh -e\`', '"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no\"',
                  '--log-file=/home/toor/rsync2.log\`' , login,
                  '@\`', ftp_addr, ':\`',  camera_name, '/ \`' ,
                  '/ \`' , 'home\`', '/\`',  login, '/\`',  camera_name)
    from inteliviz.cameras  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/rsynctest13.csv'
    lines terminated by '\r\n ;"
```

OUTPUT :

```
sshpass`-p`Password", rsync`, -avvtzh `, ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"--log-file=/home/toor/rsync2.log`lanein1@`83.100.218.219:`tester1/ `/ `home`/`lanein1/`tester1
```

excepted output:

```
sshpass -p "Pa55word" rsync   -avtzh -e  "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"  --log-file="/home/toor/rsync.log"   lanein1@11.111.111.111:AlbertstreetIN1/ /home/lanein1/AlbertstreetIN1/
```

how to insert double quotes and get rid of those back ticks.

Comment: "get rid of those back ticks." - don't add them...

Comment: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Answer (score 1):

Just use backslash before ".
In some places you use ` and ' but it's not " although it may looks like.